# One rule is not run on this Makefile

Tags: c, makefile, mingw32, windows-xp-sp3

I'm running this makefile in WinXP:

```
Package=killerapp

Sources=main.c
Resource=resource\resource.rc

Objs=$(Sources:.c=.o)
Res_obj=$(notdir $(Resource:.rc=.o))

CC_RES=windres
CC=gcc

CFLAGS=
LDFLAGS=-mwindows

%.o.c:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

$(Res_obj): $(Resource)
    $(CC_RES) $< -o $@

$(Package): $(Objs) $(Res_obj)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@

all:
    $(MAKE) $(Package)

clean:
    @del $(Objs)
    @del $(Res_obj)
    @del $(Package).exe
```

My idea is to first compile the resource file and later the source files, but seems that only windres is run and the source files are not compiled, any ideas?

Updated #1: This work as expected.

```
Package=killerapp

Sources=main.c
Resource=resource\resource.rc

Objs=$(Sources:.c=.o)
Res_obj=$(notdir $(Resource:.rc=.o))

CC_RES=windres
CC=gcc

CFLAGS=-O2 -Wall -Werror
LDFLAGS=-mwindows

all: $(Package)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

$(Res_obj): $(Resource)
    $(CC_RES) $< -o $@

$(Package): $(Res_obj) $(Objs)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@

clean:
    @del $(Objs)
    @del $(Res_obj)
    @del $(Package).exe

run: $(Package)
    ./$^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic rule is incorrect.  For Gnu make, use:

```
%.o: %.c Makefile
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<
```

You should also replace the `all` target (no command needed):

```
all: $(Package)
```

And place it before any other target rules to make it the default target.

I also suggest you enable the compiler warnings to catch common programming errors:

```
CFLAGS=-O2 -Wall -Werror
```